# How do I load a Python module from a string while preserving debug?

Tags: python, python-importlib

I'm interested in loading a Python module that has its source embedded in a C extension. It should be possible to do something with Python's `importlib` machinery like `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location` so that the source code will appear if you are debugging. How would I implement an `importlib.util.spec_from_string`?

Comment: You want to embed Python code in a C extension for Python? Can you give an example of how that would be useful? I suspect this is more of a XY problem.

Comment: It's because it's a plugin that embeds Python into another program.

Comment: Is that "other program" also a Python program, or a C program? (or are you hoping to use the C extension / plugin in binary format?) I'm asking because you'll need Python itself to execute the Python code of course and if your other program isn't Python, that's not a trivial problem. If your other program *is* Python, I think there's better ways to resolve this than to embed the script into a C extension.

Comment: The implementation of https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/zipimport.py

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to define a loader that takes the module's source from a string, and then creates and loads the module into `sys.modules`. It could be useful if the module's source is not in a file. If there is already a file then use https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly

Although `inspect.getsource(module)` works for a subclass of `importlib.abc.InspectLoader` for which it would only be necessary to define `get_source`, tracebacks and `pdb` don't appear to be willing to display the source code until you inherit from `SourceLoader`.

```
import sys
import importlib.abc, importlib.util

class StringLoader(importlib.abc.SourceLoader):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_source(self, fullname):
        return self.data
    
    def get_data(self, path):
        return self.data.encode("utf-8")
    
    def get_filename(self, fullname):
        return "<not a real path>/" + fullname + ".py"
    
module_name = "testmodule"
with open("testmodule.py", "r") as module:
    loader = StringLoader(module.read())

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(module_name, loader, origin="built-in")
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[module_name] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix, you can dump it in a temporary module, import it using `exec` and delete the temp module when you're done.

Here's a toy example:

```
dummy_src =""" 
print("imported!") 
x = 5 
""" 

with open("temp.py", "w") as f: 
    f.write(dummy_src) 

exec("import temp") 
print(temp.x)
```

Output:

```
imported!
5
```